# Easy math using multiplication/division however not getting correct answer in relation to denominator

Tags: c

So order of operations states going left to right, doing the multiplication/division first. This is clear. I am getting the right answer in one way, and then a different answer the other.

3 + 10*(16%7) + 2/4
At first I do the regular math and get 23.5
In summary, I got it by 23 + 1/2 so I just added it together.
Google also demonstrates this answer.

Then I realize that I might have to get the denominators the same, and when verifying on calculator I get just 23.
Here, in summary, I got the 23 + 1/2 and did extra denominator multiplication to get the same denominator, then divided the 46/2 and got just 23.

Which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Which is the correct way to do this?

Dont do integer math operations, the specification is clear and explaion that  dividing integers will return an integer too, so 10/2 is 5 but 10/3 is 3 and not 3.3333 as we may expect

one of the operators must be a floating/double type then..